# How to Split ConfigureServices method (of Startup) into multiple files

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, fluentvalidation, separation-of-concerns

**Separation of concerns (SoC)**

Dependency injunction registrtered in ConfigureServices (method of startup class) consist of different DI's like Repository, Fluent Validations etc.

How would I go about separating DI registration into separate files (as shown below)

[image]

Comment: Separate file same project or in different projects?You can create an extension method

Comment: @Nkosi  Its in same project. Surely i can use extensions, but is there a alternative way like reference delegations..

Comment: extension methods are the most common approach to reducing noise in the `Startup` class.

Comment: You should use the [extract method](https://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) refactoring.

Answer (score 17):

Create an extension method to hold any additional configuration you want

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static IServiceCollection AddFluentValidation(this IServiceCollection services) {

        //...add services

        return services;
    }
}
```

And then called in the `ConfigureServices` in `Startup`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    services.AddFluentValidation();
    services.AddRepository();

    //...

}
```

The use of extension methods for populating the services collection is commonly used by the framework and 3rd party extensions.

Answer (score 2):

**startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMyScoped();
            services.AddMyTransient();
        }
}
```

**AddScopedExtension.cs**

```
public static class AddScopedExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyScoped(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        // TODO : Add your Scoped Objects here
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

**AddTransientExtension.cs**

```
public static class AddTransientExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyTransient(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        // TODO : Add your Scoped Objects here
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello you can try this way

Add Extension Method

```
 public static class SlightDIModuleConfigExtension
{
     public static IWebHostBuilder UseSlightDIModuleconfig(this IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder)
    {

        return webHostBuilder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
             .GetTypes()
             .Where(myType => myType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(SlightModuleConfigure))))
            {
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                MethodInfo mi = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault();
                mi.Invoke(instance, new object[] { services });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Add abstract class

```
public abstract class SlightModuleConfigure
{
    protected virtual void Load(IServiceCollection services) { }
}
```

How to Use

in Program.cs add UseSlightDIModuleconfig()

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
          .UseSlightDIModuleconfig(); //add this .
```

Add class inherit SlightModuleConfigure like this

```
public class PayModuleConfig : SlightModuleConfigure
{
    protected override void Load(IServiceCollection services)
    {
          services.AddTransient<Ipay, PayImp>();
    }
}
```

you can refer to [SlightDIConfigure](https://github.com/toasttsao/SlightDIConfigure)

Answer (score 1):

`Partial` class - Just another way!

```
// Startup.cs
public partial class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        ConfigureScopedServices(services);
        ConfigureTransientServices(services);
    }
}

// ScopedServices.cs
public partial class Startup {
    private static void ConfigureScopedServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        Console.WriteLine("Scoped");
    }
}

// TransientServices.cs
public partial class Startup {
    private static void ConfigureTransientServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        Console.WriteLine("Transient");
    }
}
```

Comment: Never really considered using partials.

Comment: Do you mean it's a bad practice? Glad to know to know more if that's the case.

Comment: Not sure if its bad practice or just a personal preference.  I generally do not use partials because it can make code harder to maintain.