# Configure logging in the business layer of a N-layer application

Tags: asp.net-core, logging, n-tier-architecture

Recently I started working on a project which basically has the following structure:

[image]

As you can see, now we only support logging on the presentation layer where we have try/catch blocks expecting to handle errors from the business layer. So far, so good. But, recently I started to realize that I will need to log some processing information as well. Not only exceptions. If possible, in the same file where **Presentation App 1**, for example, is storing its logs.

So, for that purpose, the way I imagine it is that my business layer has some kind of generic interface implemented by Serilog and log4net (and probably other providers) and use it to do its logging. That's because I don't really want to add a specific logging package in my business layer project. In other words, I want it to be independent. So, I tried to look at some best practices. I covered [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/managing-cross-cutting-concerns-the-logger-and-logging/) article which explains *Managing Cross Cutting Concerns* but I couldn't really understand how it will fit my case.

How can I use the logger (in my business layer project) which was dependency injected in my startup application?

**UPDATE**:
The way I dependency inject my logger into the worker service clients is as follows:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder =>
                {
                    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                        .Build();
                    var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                        .CreateLogger();
                    loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger, dispose: true);
                })
```

where **loggingBuilder** is of type *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder* and the actual logger that I use in the application and is dependecy injected through the constructor of the worker

```
public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, IBusinessLayerService businessLayerService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _businessLayerService = businessLayerService;
        }
```

is of type *Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger
```

you'll keep things pretty standard without any dependencies to neither Serilog nor log4net in *Data Layer* and *Business Layer*.

You inject logger like this

```
ILogger<YourBusinessClass>
```

This article describes how to use Serilog with default logger:

https://vmsdurano.com/serilog-and-asp-net-core-split-log-data-using-filterexpression/

`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` should be available to your application through `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` which has a dependency to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Configuration` which has a dependency to `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`. Hence, no need for adding extra Nuget package for `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`.

Comment: I just updated my question with the actual code that is implemented in two of the service worker client apps. But does that mean that I will need Microsoft.Extensions.Logging in each of my client apps?

Comment: @user2128702: Please see update at the end of my answer. BR

Comment: @user2128702: Thanks for accepting my answer. You may find this strategy for catching exceptions in app layer interesting. Disclaimer: My answer for a different question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65645322/14072498 BR

Comment: I don't see how you actually make the Business Logic Layer work with ILogger. Can you put an example please? The think is that I instantiate my BLL class in the API project but this instantiation needs to be passed a ILogger parameter. But the problem is that ILogger cannot be instantiated so how can I pass an ILogger as parameter to my BLL class constructor?

Comment: @VictorCallegari: Do you wire up your BLL component in Startup#ConfigureServices like this: `services.AddSingleton<IMyBll, MyBll>();`? If so, constructor injection should work without any extra code. If not, please let me know what kind of error message you get.  BR

Comment: @RoarS. Thanks for the response. I thought that is what I have to do yes but then I started questioning and wondering what if I have a Business Logic Layer with 1000 different classes, do I have to inject each of them in as a service in the Startup#ConfigureServices? That did not sound like a good pattern or standard to my mind. I could be wrong and I want to learn more. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorCallegari: Startup#ConfIgureServices may be split up into pieces of more managable size like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50898192/14072498
BR